# Bootstrap range sider is not working in Bootstrap Modal box

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-slider

I am trying to embed an slider in Bootstrap modal but it does not work in modal box however if i put the code outside the modal box it works fine.

Here is my code

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="frown_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="content-box-large pull-left col-md-12">

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <h4>Rate <span class="friends_name"></span></h4>
                            </div>
                            <hr/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="rated_value" class="rated_value" value="" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="friends_id" class="friends_id" value="" />
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <input type="text" class="span2 slider" value="" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="0" data-slider-orientation="horizontal" data-slider-selection="after" data-slider-tooltip="hide" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <img src="" class="friends_img" width="320" height="240" />
                            </div>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary pull-center send_ajax_btn" id="submit_btn" href="javascript:void(0);">Save</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary pull-center delete_no" id="close_popup" href="javascript:void(0);">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is Jquery

```
$(".slider").slider();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don’t think Bootstrap has a slider implemented - what library are you using for the slider?

Comment: http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/

Comment: The slider works within a modal. Here are a few Fiddles proving it: With exemplar data: (https://jsfiddle.net/4p8h534n/) and with your example (https://jsfiddle.net/2c6ujexq/)